# How can you allow <3 or any tag < any character not ending with < or > sanitize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitize, strip-tags

sanitize("hello") => hello

but if I have

sanitize("<3")  it return 3 only

I want it should allow string if not end with < or >

like if I do
sanitize("<3 >4") it should simply return <3 >4

Comment: have you considered instead URL encoding them?

Comment: URL encoding has nothing to do with HTML.

Answer (score 3):

First off, Rails' built-in sanitize doesn't deal with malformed markup.

I highly recommend you use the Sanitize gem for dealing with anything that could potentially be malformed:

https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize

But your issue is non-html-encoded character entities. Run them through CGI.escape()

```
require 'cgi'
CGI.escape('<3') # => "%3C3"
```

For the finish:

```
require 'cgi'
Sanitize.clean( CGI.escape('<3') ) # => "%3C3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do a pre-clean on your content to properly encode values you want to preserve. For example:

```
content.gsub!(/\<3/, '&lt;3')
```

The only concern is that your cleaner might double-escape this to `&amp;lt;3` which can prove annoying. At least that's possible to reverse if required.

It's not possible to "sanitize" without stripping invalid brackets. Some browsers will choke on that sort of thing and it can render your page entirely corrupted if not handled correctly.